# phpmyadmin does not work

Tags: javascript, php

Welcome to phpMyAdmin

Error
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

my config page

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
```

Comment: is your database on a webspace? are you tring to connect it from localhost to remote server? more info = fastest solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user root@localhost with the password root does not exist. 
If you can connect to the database by some other means, you should use the credentials you are using there. But using the password 'root' does not seem very secure.

Comment: It should work with blank password anyway ?

Comment: If you leave the password blank in the configuration, PhpMyAdmin will ask for the password. If the password of the root user is really empty, that is even more insecure than the password 'root'.

Answer (score 0):

You should also confirm that your host is really 127.0.0.1 or localhost. Some web hosts use a different hostname.

Comment: But there is a database running on localhost. The error message is from MySQL. I don't think hosters which are using different servers for databases have a database running on their webservers as well.